# The expression seems not good ( mathematical operator)

Tags: math-mode

I am trying to write an expression but the output is no[image]t the same as expected.

Try:

```
$c_{j_{1}}^{L,n} = \displaystyle\sum_{m=1}^{M-1} (t_{j{_1}m})$
```

How can I correct it. Please help me.

Comment: Try `${c_{j_1}}^{L,n} = \displaystyle\sum_{m=1}^{M-1} (t_{j_1 m})$`.

Comment: @HenriMenke thanks a lot it is the exact answer of my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be in display math mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
c_{j_{1}}{\!}^{L,n} = \sum_{m=1}^{M-1} t_{j^{}_{1}m}
\]

\end{document}
```

The `\!` backs up a little; the empty superscript for `j` pushes the subscript a bit down.

[image]

Comment: For complicated nested indices one may want to separate them with commas. For instance, in panel/time-series data, it is unclear what `x_{2t-1}` stands for at first glance (even for master students). If horizontal space is not an issue, you may write the last thing as `t_{j_1,m}` if it really has to be inline math.